# cakephp generateTreeList Limit depth

Tags: cakephp, tree

How can i limit depth of the tree returned by generatetreelist in cakephp?

the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html)  shows that i can't pass a depth.  What would be an elegant way to get around this?

Comment: note sure, but could the $recursive in `generateTreeList($conditions=null, $keyPath=null, $valuePath=null, $spacer= '_', $recursive=null)` work here? The documentation states: "The number of levels deep to fetch associated records"

Comment: No, thats the models attached to the records in the tree, not the depth of the tree.

Comment: maybe there isn't yet - from looking at the code. you could always just "drop" the unnecessary data that is fetched after the query. But you are probably looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Sometimes just knowing that it isn't me doing it wrong is enough.

Answer (score 0):

[Node level (Depth)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#node-level-depth) was added in CakePHP 2.7

I guess if you cache the level as explained in the book you can specify the required levels as a `condition` in the `generateTreeList` call...